# list of fourier coefficients of modular forms

Tags: modular-forms

I wanted to ask if there is somewhere a comprehensive list of modular forms with their Fourier  expansions - coefficients... I need this to compare some sequences with coefficients of modular forms...
Thanks

Comment: You could try putting your sequences into oeis.org.

Comment: Does http://www.lmfdb.org/ allow search by $q$-coefficients?

Comment: +1 Something reasonably comprehensive would be rather nice.